# Simple proxy asp.net error

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I don't know why this .aspx gives me:...

A DOWNLOADPROMPT, AN ANNOYING DOWNLOAD.

I don't know what is wrong.

My code:

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" %>


<script runat="server">
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        var strURL = "http://www.google.com";

        System.Net.WebResponse objResponse = default(System.Net.WebResponse);
        System.Net.WebRequest objRequest = default(System.Net.WebRequest);
        string result = null;
        objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL);
        objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //clean up StreamReader 
        sr.Close();

        //WRITE OUTPUT
        Response.ContentType = "application/html";
        Response.Write(result);//""
        Response.Flush();//""

    }
</script>
```

I still don't know what's wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a single file page model there are two problems preventing your code from working.  The page_load method signature is wrong and the context already exists, it's not passed in.  Update the code to this:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        var strURL = "http://www.google.com";

        System.Net.WebResponse objResponse = default(System.Net.WebResponse);
        System.Net.WebRequest objRequest = default(System.Net.WebRequest);
        string result = null;
        objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL);
        objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //clean up StreamReader 
        sr.Close();

        //WRITE OUTPUT
        Response.ContentType = "text/html";//remove context
        Response.Write(result);//""

    }
</script>
```

Comment: @user131008 - IE9 works fine.  Try a different browser / version.  Then tell us what version you use.  You'll likely have to update your contentType with some trickery on old IE (roughly 7 and older)

Comment: Same for Firefox and Chrome! Except that Chrome does not asks you whether you want to download or not!

Comment: @user131008 - I updated the ContentType.  Try it again it should work.  Text/html is the default so you can actually remove that line if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have "global" code, you have to encapsulate it inside a method.

Something like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // Your code...
    }
</script>
```

This executes your code during the loading of the page.

*(I've not checked whether your code makes sense. This Google thing looks kind of strange to me...)*

**Update:**

You also have to [import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) the namespaces you require like e.g. for [`WebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Net" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // Your code...
    }
</script>
```

Repeat this `<%@ Import...%>` directive for all namespaces you use. Or use the full qualified name of the class, including the namespace, e.g. `System.Net.WebResponse`.

**Second update:**

OK, this is just a wild guess to remove (one of?) the logical errors:

Instead of:

```
var strURL = context.Server.UrlDecode(context.Request["http://www.google.com"]);
```

write:

```
var strURL = "http://www.google.com";
```

and see whether it works better (based on your comment that you are using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415317/107625)).

**Third (final?) update:**

If this doesn't help either, try debugging it inside Visual Studio (Express) and set breakpoints, step through your code, inspect variables, etc. [Here is a short introduction to debugging](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging).

Comment: @user131008 I've helped you removing the compilation errors, I can't help removing the logical errors ;-)

Comment: From here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280739/how-can-i-make-a-very-simple-web-proxy-using-asp-net

Comment: @user131008 OK, I've changed my answer.