# Changing Youtube URL using Proxy ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, proxy, youtube

I am just a newbie in web Programming and probably I am asking a stupid question I am trying to write a code to visit YouTube's Video. For a specific video I am getting the following URL

http://r12---sn-aig7knes.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?newshard=yes&source=youtube&sver=3&expire=1371151990&mv=m&mt=1371131974&ms=au&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=8&gcr=gb&itag=18&sparams=cp,gcr,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&fexp=919118,900352,921047,924605,928201,901208,929123,929121,929915,929906,929907,929125,925714,929919,929119,931202,928017,912512,912515,912521,906906,904488,931913,904830,919373,906836,933701,932211,932216,912711,930618,930621,929606,910075&id=51e3eda310e1252c&key=yt1&ip=92.40.254.100&upn=uMcqpTSaHTs&cp=U0hWRlFQT19OSkNONl9JSlNKOkJBOTRMalY1djFr&fallback_host=tc.v5.cache3.c.youtube.com&signature=6FE5AC5A4FCA9A02C6AD7AF94E161194868C0DA2.91D27D9BA120F0DA53049BE5087301F08CC27870

I want to pass through it through some proxy to modify it so that I can access it even if  Youtube is blocked. 
I hope my question is clear

Comment: Do you want to write a proxy to provide your customers with functionality, in case they cannot access YouTube? Or are you trying to write a proxy for yourself for when you cannot access YouTube?

Comment: yes.I want to provide this facility to the users of my website.

Comment: Well I want that I have search box in which people put their queries like they do in Youtube and in result they see the video. I have solved this problem by fetching the link. Downloading it and show at my page as I am hosting the website at my home.  but I want to do it direct without downloading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that each link you extract from YouTube will only work for your specific IP address. You cannot hand-off this link to another IP address or it won't work. This is why "YouTube Video Downloaders" are all scripted client side - so that a visiting user accesses YouTube from their machine and gets a YouTube link tailored for their IP address.

I'm not sure a web-based proxy would accomplish what you want because the visitor to your site would have a different IP address than your server which would be accessing YouTube. You would have to find some way to tunnel their request directly to YouTube.

You would most likely have to download/stream the video to your server and then offer it to your clients.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's a tough one, considering how video streaming works I'd go so far as to say ASP.NET cannot do it.

Take a look at iisproxy.net, and this article: [How can I make a VERY simple web proxy using ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280739/how-can-i-make-a-very-simple-web-proxy-using-asp-net)